# Unable to save Cartopy generated figure to pdf file using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm using Cartopy to generate a bunch of plots on a lat/long grid (upgrading from Matplotlib's Basemap) and even though the plotting isn't kicking up any errors my code fails when I try to save the figure to a multiple page PDF file using Matplotlib's `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages`.

Here are the relevant portion of code:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib import colorbar, cm, pyplot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

(fig, axis) = pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={"projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()})

fout = PdfPages("Junk.pdf")
fout.savefig(fig)
```

I've verified that `fig` is of type `matplotlib.figure.Figure`.

The error that I get is:

```
File "./plot_cfba.py", line 326, in <module>
    fout_tmp.savefig(fig[0])
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2445, in savefig
    figure.savefig(self, format="pdf", **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2180, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2089, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2503, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 372, in draw
    gl._draw_gridliner(background_patch=self.background_patch)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/gridliner.py", line 338, in _draw_gridliner
    x_lc = mcollections.LineCollection(lines, **collection_kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1331, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 974, in update
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 974, in <listcomp>
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "/data/science_TC/kmueller/toolkit/python/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 970, in _update_property
    .format(type(self).__name__, k))
AttributeError: 'LineCollection' object has no property 'xloc'
```

I'm using matplotlib version 3.1.2, Cartopy 0.17.0 and python 3.6.9.

Is there a mismatch between these versions of Matplotlib and Cartopy?  Do I need to upgrade one of them to match the other?

This code used to work fine but now that I'm making my maps using Cartopy things broke.

Comment: In your sample code `fig` is a single figure instance, but the line which produced the error shows `savefig(fig[0])`, indicating `fig` is an array or array-like. Why is `fig` indexed in the code which produces the error but not your example code?

Comment: The example code you posted runs without error for me on matplotlib 3.2 and python 3.8.

Comment: The "fig" vs "fig[0]" is a byproduct of sloppy cutting and pasting.  In the real code fig is a list of figures, which I save to the PdfPages file one by one.

Comment: DopplerShift: which version of Cartopy are you running?

Comment: I can't replicate this error running your example code with Python 3.6.9, Cartopy 0.17.0 and Matplotlib 3.1.2. The issue is either with your installation or configuration, or it is caused by something not captured in the example, without seeing more of the code I can't say for sure which.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was entirely of my own making.  The "axis.gridlines" call should pass in "xlocs" and "ylocs" rather than "xloc" and "yloc".

I should have looked at the error message more carefully.  I got caught out by the fact that the "savefig" call bombed when the problem was really in "axis.gridlines" thereby sending my thinking in the complete wrong direction.

Comment: You can always click to accept your own answers and the good answers to your questions. Please give feedback if you dont accept them.